# Date Difference in Freemarker

Tags: javascript, html, netsuite, freemarker, suitescript

I need difference between 2 dates in freemarker. One date is from system while the other date must be hardcoded to 18/02/2021.

Can anyone guide me how to do that because i am facing parsing issues.

My code so far:

```
 <#assign difference=(record.trandate?long / 86400000)?round - (hardcodedDate?long / 86400000)?round />
```

`record.trandate` is the date from system, while `hardcodedDate` is my entered date.

I tried assigning both below, but didt work:

```
        <#assign hardcodedDate = "Feb 18, 2021 2:07:30 PM" />
        <#assign hardcodedDate = "Mar 18, 2021 2:07:30 PM" />
```

In the end, all that is required is difference between the 2 dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hardcodedDate`is declared as a String, you have to transform it into a date, using  the [`date`](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_string_date) built-in.

For example:

```
<#assign date1 = "Feb 18, 2021 12:07:30 PM"?date("MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a") />
<#assign date2 = "Mar 18, 2021 2:07:30 PM"?date("MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a") />
<#assign difference=(date1?long / 86400000)?round - (date2?long / 86400000)?round />
```

Comment: That should be `?datetime`. Since you only use the result for `?long`, it doesn't matter in this case, but in other use cases it can be confusing, as the time part will not be shown if you print the value.

Comment: Perfectly worked! Thanks a ton to @obourgain